# Knowing which elements from dataset went into tallest bin in histogram? MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to know which elements from my data set went into the tallest bin in a bivariate histogram, and have not found information on how to do this online. I suspect this is possible since it is fairly useful.

I know I can do some other code that helps me find it but I was wondering if there is a succinct way of doing this. For example I could search through the dataset with a conditional that helps me extract the things falling into the bins but I'm not interested in that. Right now I have written

```
X = [Eavg,Estdev];
hist3(X,[15 15])
```

The result is a 15x15 bin bivariate histogram. I want to extract the elements in the tallest bin in a very terse manner.

I'm doing a statistical mechanics (Monte Carlo) simulation, if its worth mentioning...

Comment: Check out the [`discretize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature `[N, CEN] = hist3(...` returns bincounts and center of bins. Bin centers can be converted to bin edges. Then edges can be use to find which data elements fall into a specific bin.

```
 X =  randi([1 100],10,2);
[N, CEN] = hist3(X,[5 5]);
%find row and column of highest value of histogram
%since there may be multiple histogram values that 
%are equal to maximum value then we select the first one
[r,c]= find(N==max(N(:)),1);
%convert cell of bin centers to vector
R = [CEN{1}];
C = [CEN{2}];
%convert bin centers to edges 
%realmax used to include values that 
%are beyond the first and the last computed edges
ER = [-realmax R(1:end-1)+diff(R)/2 realmax];
EC = [-realmax C(1:end-1)+diff(C)/2 realmax];
%logical indices of rows where data fall into specified bin
IDX = X(:,1)>= ER(r) & X(:,1)< ER(r+1) & X(:,2)>= EC(c) & X(:,2)< EC(c+1)
```

Comment: nice! I may need to study it a bit but seems to work perfectly.